# Laravel: get the most purchases product for current user

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables here (order_lists, order_details, products)

Table order_lists contain the following `user_id`

Table order_details contain the following `order_lists_id` `product_id`

Table products contain all the products details.

the three tables are related to each others in models.

I need to select the most purchases items from table `order_details` based this `user_id`.

I made very basic Eloquent query which will select 6 products for this user but stuck on how to get the most purchases product

```
$mostPurchases = OrderList::where( 'user_id', Auth::id() )
                 ->with( [
                   'orderDetails' => function ( $query ) {
                         $query->with( 'productId' );
                    }
                 ] )->take( 6 )->get();
```

in `order_details` I need to count the user most purchases product.

> UPDATE

As @party-ring suggest to use DB::raw query this is the final query looks like.

```
$usId          = Auth::id();
        $mostPurchases = DB::select( DB::raw( 'SELECT product_id, count(*) from order_details
            LEFT JOIN order_lists ON order_details.order_lists_id = order_lists.id
            WHERE order_lists.user_id = ' . $usId . '
            group by product_id
            order by count(*) DESC
            LIMIT 6' ) );
```

> Update

```
DB::table( 'products' )
              ->where( 'soft_delete', '!=', 1 )
              ->leftJoin( 'order_details', 'products.id', '=', 'order_details.product_id' )
              ->select( DB::raw( 'count(*) as pro_count, product_id' ) )
              ->leftJoin( 'order_lists', 'order_details.order_lists_id', '=', 'order_lists.id' )
              ->where( 'order_lists.user_id', '=', $usId )
              ->orderBy( 'pro_count', 'DESC' )
              ->groupBy( 'product_id' )
              ->take( 6 )
              ->get();
```

but still I got only the pro_count, and product_id

```
    {
        "pro_count": 22,
        "product_id": 733
    },
    {
        "pro_count": 15,
        "product_id": 85
    },
```

I need the product details within the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this by using `join` and `DB::raw` as I have found it can be more efficient than Eloquent when dealing with large datasets opposed to a function query - also I find it a little easier to build up my queries in this way.

```
 select(DB::raw('SELECT product_id, count(*) from order_details
     LEFT JOIN `order_lists` ON order_details.order_lists_id = order_lists.id
     WHERE order_lists.user_id = :authUser
     group by product_id
     order by count(*) DESC
     LIMIT 6', ['authUser => Auth::id()']);
```

You might need to play around with this a little as I don't know if you will need to specify the table names in your query.

This is adding together your `order_lists` and `order_details tables`, limiting it to that of the auth user, grouping it by the product id, ordering it by the count of those product purchases for the user and limiting it to 6 results.

Comment: I try something like this `DB::table( 'order_details' )->select( DB::raw( 'SELECT product_id, count(*) from order_details
LEFT JOIN `order_lists` ON order_details.order_lists_id = order_lists.id
WHERE order_lists.user_id = :authUser
group by product_id
     order by count(*) DESC
LIMIT 6' ) )->get();` but gives error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT product_id, count(*) from order_details`

Comment: What did you have to change to get it to work in the end? :)

Comment: I updated my question please see the update, thanks

Comment: can you please help how to return the products details with the response as I got now `(product_id, pro_count)`

Comment: I would save the `product_id`s from the above query and run a new one - `Products::whereIn('id', $productIDs)->get();`

Comment: I try to do something like this `$proDetails = Product::whereIn('id', $mostPurchases->product_id)->get();` but got error `Property [product_id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: Try `$productIDs = $mostPurchases->pluck('product_id');`